# Create a Generic AttributeConverter[JDO] with JsonConverter

Tags: jackson, jdo, datanucleus

I´m using JDO + DataNucleus and implement a AttributeConverter with Jackson Json.
Already have a generic method for AttributeConverter:

```
@Override
    public String convertToDatastore(ArrayList<Object> alist) {
        String jsonString = null;
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(alist);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }
```

But, in Deserialize JSON to Object i read that i need to specify the class

```
 public ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> convertToAttribute(String s) {

    ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> obj = null;
    try
    {
        obj =   mapper.readValue(s, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
                List.class, TelephoneNumber.class));
    }
    catch (JsonParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (JsonMappingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return obj;
}
```

**but  jsonString is a arrayList object**

how can I do this?

thanks

Comment: How my method get a Json String and mount the ArrayList based on the type of object. Instead of being to create a ConvertToAttribute for wich type of object ...

Comment: doesn't this post explain that ? https://patrickgrimard.com/2011/12/05/convert-a-json-collection-from-string-to-list-with-jackson/   alternatively just use standard API javax.json ?

Comment: @NeilStockton Thank you, I'll read.